# DataGridView databinding

Tags: c#, data-binding, datagridview, datagridviewcomboboxcell

I give a simple example to explain what I want:

I defined a class called `Student`, it has two properties: *Name* and *Subjects*.

```
public class Student()
{
     public string Name;
     public List<string> Subjects;
}
```

I created two instances of Student class, for example:

```
List<string> jackSubjects = new List<string>();
jackSubjects.Add("Math");
jackSubjects.Add("Physics");
Student Jack = new Student("Jack", jackSubjects);
List<string> alanSubjects = new List<string>();
alanSubjects.Add("Accounting");
alanSubjects.Add("Science");
Student Alan = new Student("Alan", alanSubjects);
```

Then I create a List studentList:

```
List<Student> studentList = new List<Student>();
studentList.Add(Jack);
studentList.Add(Alan);
```

My question is, is there any way I can databind this `studentList` with a `DataGridView`, something like the following:

```
dataGridView.DataSource = studentList;
```

The first column is the student name and the second column is a `combobox` which shows all the subjects for the student.

Thank you for your time in advance.

Comment: Did you tried to bind the `studentList` with `dataGridView.DataSource = studentList`? then that's the one way to bind the `list` to `DataGridView`. what is your main problem here?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this will work:

1. Add a RowDataBound event to your grid and create a template column to hold the dropdownlist for the subjects:

   ```
   <asp:GridView ID="dataGridView" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" OnRowDataBound="dataGridView_RowDataBound">
      <Columns>
          <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" />
          <asp:TemplateField>
              <ItemTemplate>
                  <asp:DropDownList ID="subjects" runat="server" ></asp:DropDownList>
              </ItemTemplate>
          </asp:TemplateField>
      </Columns>
   ```
2. Then on code behind handle the RowDataBound event as so:

   ```
   protected void dataGridView_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
   {
     if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
     {
       var ddl = (e.Row.FindControl("subjects") as DropDownList);
       ddl.DataSource = (e.Row.DataItem as Student).Subjects;
       ddl.DataBind();
     }
   }
   ```

Renders:
[image]

BTW, your Student class should look like this:

```
public class Student
{
     public string Name {get;set;}
     public List<string> Subjects {get;set;}

     public Student(string name, List<string> subjects)
     {
         Name = name;
         Subjects = subjects;
     }
}
```